# Is 'The longer the prediction period, the more easy and accurate is the knowledge of the water and trees' a conditional sentence without if?

Tags: commas, conditionals

the following sentence:

> The longer the prediction period, the more easy and accurate is
>   the knowledge of the water and trees.

Is this a conditional sentence without if? Could I rewrite it as "if the prediction period becomes longer, the more easy and accurate is the knowledge of water and tress"? Or do I misunderstand something here. I was mainly thinking about this to understand why a comma is used.

Thank you for any help

Comment: No, you can't rewrite using ***if*** instead of a comparative form (***the longer***, in your case). The most common version of this idiomatic construction is the totally "symmetrical" ***The more [X], the more [Y]***, but whatever words you have instead of ***more*** should at least be "comparators" - *The **bigger** they are the **harder** they fall*, for example. Which could be recast as ***If** they are bigger they fall harder*, but you can't just have one half of your juxtaposition using the ***the** [comparator]* element. It's both or neither. I consider commas irrelevant here, btw.

Comment: "the more easy is the knowledge" is incomplete here.  "The longer the prediction period, the more easily and accurately is knowledge of the water and trees obtained."  Sound good?

Comment: Thank you, I was mainly trying to figure out why I wanted to place a comma there. Also, I think that in most examples I could find on the internet, a comma was used. However, I also saw examples without a comma. Coming from a native language practically no comma is placed or omitted without a rule, I thought I could find a rule here. It seems though as if there was none.